# Badges displayed incorrectly?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It seems that there's something odd going on with badges. If we take some random user, say 1719, which has one account, and check the user page http://stackexchange.com/users/1719/jelon, then we can see that it says user has 3 bronze badges. Now if we try to retrieve user or badge information for that user via API, we will see 5 (4 bronze, one silver): http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1719/badges.

Is it something wrong with API or StackExchange pages are not displayed the information correctly (or maybe applying some default filter, for example time-based)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stackexchange.com user ids are not the same as stackoverflow.com user ids (are not the same as Server Fault's, Super User's, etc., etc.).

Stack Overflow user 1719 is [voyce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1719/voyce), who has the five badges the API returns.

Jelon is user 2326, and the API returns his [3 badges](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/2326/badges) corrrect too.

Comment: So if I got it right, then by accessing http://stackexchange.com/users/1719/ we end up on a page of the user Jelon (with 3 badges). If we access http://stackoverflow.com/users/1719/, that will be ID of a different user (because it's SO rather than SE) - voyce, having 5 badges.

In that case how do we get badges info through API for the StackExchange user based on his StackExhange ID/URL? Or if every SE user has an ID on SO (but different), then how to find SO ID (that 2326)?

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence - se.com isn't exposed via the API, the site itself is just aggregating data from the proper Q&A sites.  User ids on se.com happen to be account_ids, which can be used to find proper site users via [/users/{ids}/associated](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users).